# How to add new target type to autoconf?

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I would like to extend our existing autotools build system with a new cross compilation target type: chrome-pnacl

This is not defined in config.sub, and when I try to invoke configure  --target=chromebook-pnacl, I get: machine `chromebook' not recognized

What's the proper way to add this new target?

Answer (score 0):

When I look in the comments in [config.sub](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD) I read this:

```
Please send patches to <config-patches@gnu.org>.
```

This is a GNU mailman mailing list. And you may want to subscribe to that mailing list [config-patches@gnu.org](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/config-patches) where you can probably get more specific help.

I currently don't see chromebook or pnacl anywhere in that script.